# How to make IntelliJ recognize path in require

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to navigate to the file './common/KeyValue' if I click on the string given to require. I tried to inject 'file' as a language reference but that did no help.

```
var Store = require('./common/KeyValue');
var SimpleRow = require('./components/SimpleRow');
```

Comment: Do you *want* to click?  What if you could use a keyboard shortcut?